# I get "Open SQL Script" upon MySQL startup (in Workbench)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have 3 connections configured in the MySQL Workbench and lately as soon as I run the workbench I get this "Open SQL Script" dialog.

Steps:
1) Right click MySQL Notifier (1.1.4)
2) Click on "SQL Editor..."
3) Expected: Workbench Home (1 tab open)
Actual result: the tab for the 3rd connection is automatically open and on top of that I get this "Open SQL Script" dialog.

Additionally I would love to be able to change the default connection that opens, but I could not find any of this anywhere.

Help is appreciated! Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look where you are clicking in MySQL Notifier. For each instance MySQL Workbench (and hence MySQL Notifier) found there's a separate menu entry which you can use to open the application for. The notifier is just trying to help you to get quicker to some standard work. If you just want to open MySQL Workbench then don't use the notifier. Create a shortcut for it and put in a good place instead.

**Update**

In order to clarify look at this image:

[image]

As you can see there's more than one "SQL Editor..." entry (one for each connection in MySQL Workbench). But even if you only have one connection, the menu entry "SQL Editor..." is meant to open ... well... the SQL editor. In addition it asks for an SQL file you may want to open. That's just how it is designed. If you don't want that click `Cancel`. There's no dedicated menu entry to just open MySQL Workbench with the home screen. If you want that better place a shortcut to the application on your desktop.

Regarding a "default connection": there's no such thing as a default connection. You can pass in a connection name on the command line if you want to open a specific connection. You can use the shortcut you can create and add the parameter "-query " to it.

Comment: Clicking on a Workbench shortcut (as opposed to using the notifier) might work better, but it doesn't answer my question. I gave very detailed steps on what I do to cause this situation and I am not sure what you mean by separate menu entries. I have one instance of the WB with 3 MySQL connections.